# How do I install Ubuntu on a hard drive using a USB flash drive that already has a full version of Ubuntu installed?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, hard-drive

I have a new hard drive that I want to install Ubuntu on. And I have a USB flash drive already running a full version (not "try") of Ubuntu. I want to use the flash drive to install Ubuntu on the new hard drive.

[it is suggested that this a duplicate question, but the suggested prior question is about accessing an encrypted hard drive. My question has nothing to do with that.]

Comment: You might want to take a look at ma answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/768970/how-to-make-persistent-live-ubuntu-of-16-04/769124#769124), this describes an installation done via 'debootstrap' for 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Seems like everyone else is confused about what you're trying to do. Try the instructions [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/54388/301745), but instead of selecting a flash drive, select the HDD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I can, how do I install Ubuntu from Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64504/if-i-can-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-ubuntu)

Comment: Just copy ISO to a folder like /boot or separate partition and folder like /ISO. And add grub loop mount boot stanza to 40_custom. http://askubuntu.com/questions/388382/multi-partition-multi-os-bootable-usb/388484#388484  Example has /boot/iso, so another folder in /boot created. Getting path correct is usually the biggest issue. And path has to be as if it is not mounted by Ubuntu as from grub nothing is mounted yet.